# db.close() promise pending : Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed

Tags: javascript, mongodb, jestjs

Trying to learn jest, with the below code the test doesn't terminate. The status of db.close promise is still pending.

I am getting following message when I execute the test. Can you help me resolve this? Thanks.

Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.

This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.

```
test('Should be ', async () => {

    /*DO NOT call the next four function directly,  check if a  merchant/terminal exists before starting
    a transaction and insert document if required.*/
    //functions.insertTerminalRecordInMongo();
    //functions.insertTerminalRecordInMongo();

    var record = await functions.getMongoField('terminal', {'attributes.TID': 'T55001001'});
    //functions.deleteTerminalRecordInMongo('terminal',{'attributes.TID' :'T55001001'})
    DE22Test.buildTransactionAndSend({MTI: "1104", dataElements: {DE22: "XYZ"}})
    expect(functions.getAsRequestField('DE22')).toBe("XYZ")
    expect(functions.getAsResponseField('DE39')).toBe("00")
    expect(functions.getAsResponseField('DE01')).toBe("00")
})
```

Function to retrieve the document from mongodb.

```
 //Return a mongo record based on collectionName and FieldName
    getMongoField: (collectionName, queryElement) => {
        console.info("Querying Mongo");
        mongoClient.connect(uri, function (err, db) {
            if (err) throw err;
            dbo = db.db("axis")
            dbo.collection(collectionName).find({}, queryElement).toArray(function (err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.info('Queried document', result[0]);
            });
            db.close()
        })
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I wished to comment but due to less reputation, I can't.
From the code snippet, database operations are async in nature which means that you need to implement async code so at the end the code will terminate after database is closed.

```
const db = await mongoClient.connect(uri)
// Do your tasks
await db.close()
```

## Edit

Don't forget to wrap your code around try catch block for error handling.

Comment: Thank you, I have the getMongoField function declared in a seperate javascript, how can I implement async? Thanks, Prashan

Comment: Oh,  for that  export the function from that file, and run as ` await function_name() `, make sure that parent function inside which you'll run this function must be async.

Comment: I suggest you look over material on async-await and promises.